# Problem with triggering change event from Now() function cell

Tags: excel, vba, events, eventtrigger

- I've got a spreadsheet that imports some data from a website and then filters and sorts it into a list. It reimports the data every 5 minutes.
- I also have a cell, cell O1 located on the worksheet called *FinalDisplay*, that uses the following formula to timestamp when the last update occurred:

`=TEXT(NOW(),"hh:mm AM/PM")`

- Lastly, I have a macro, called *FilterSort* that filters the list and then sorts the remaining results. This macro works fine when I run it manually.

What I am trying to do is have the change event of cell O1 getting updated at the time of the reimport trigger the macro to run so that, when the data is imported, it is automatically re-filtered/sorted. When the re-import happens and the timestamp is updated, however, nothing else happens.

The problem I *think* is that I think the Now() function getting recalcuated may not be handled as a change event because when I just punch in a number and overwrite the formula, the macro fires and everything works.

I've read that Now() is (or can be) a "volatile function" which might be handled differently than what I am expecting. Am I correct in thinking that this is the problem? Is there a way to resolve it so that the macro is called when the timestamp cell is updated?

[image: My excel vba Code]

Comment: I honestly would not use `NOW` like this to timestamp... how exactly is the data getting imported?

Comment: You need `Worksheet_Calculate` if you're looking for an event that fires when formulas recalculate.

Comment: @Big I'm using the Import Data from Web feature to populate a separate worksheet with the data and then mirroring it over to the FinalDisplay sheet.

Comment: As you mentioned now is volatile so it will be recalculated every time any cell changes anywhere on the workbook.  Even if you capture the correct event e.g calculate, most likely you will end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: if your code is downloading the data then why not fire FilterSort after all download part completes.

Comment: ^ This......... seems like you're dealing with an XY problem here.

Comment: @cyb I figured there is a smarter way to do it but my knowledge/skills are very limited so I proceeded in the only way that I was able to figure out how. I didn't write any code for the data import. I set that up using Excel's interface and I don't see that any VBA code that I could access was created as a result. If there were, I'd absolutely have just dropped the macro call into it.